# Android actionmode and moving item up-down

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

I'm trying to activate the movement (up and down) to move a recycleview item after the action mode has been activated.

Basically I have implemented the viewHolder onLongPress () like this:

```
@Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            mTouchHelper.startDrag(this);
            if (!isMultiSelect)
             {
                selectedIds = new HashMap<>();
                isMultiSelect = true;
                if (actionMode == null) {
                    actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) parentFragment.requireActivity()).
                            startSupportActionMode(new ActionBarCallback(parentFragment.getActivity()
                            )); //show ActionMode.
                }
            }
            multiSelect(getAdapterPosition());
        }
```

When I press and hold the item for the first time, action mode is activated and I do not have the possibility to move the item up and down.
I am trying to allow the movement of the item when the actionmode is activated and to deactivate the actionmode when I am moving the element.

Do you have any ideas on how I can make action mode and item moving coexist?

Comment: I'm not sure on an actual solution but I'd argue that moving the items should differ from selecting multiple. You might want an icon that when long pressed denotes a move action or perhaps a select action. I mean reasonably how would you know if a user wants to select multiple or move? It's not that easy so seperate this in your UI

Comment: I had considered the idea of ​​inserting a special button. What I wanted to accomplish is what google did in its note application, "google Keep".

Answer (score 0):

I think this article may be useful, https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504

I also used Google Keep. In general, the ActionMode can work with "normal UI" http://prntscr.com/vr4j7n

There is no conflict between the movement(up or down) of RecycleView and ActionMode.